# R put multiple randomForest objects into a vector

Tags: r, list, random-forest

I am curious if R has the ability to place objects into vectors/lists/arrays/etc.  I am using the randomforest package to work on subsets of a larger piece of data and would like to store each version in a list.  It would be similar to this:

```
answers <- c()
for(i in 1:10){
x <- round((1/i), 3)
answers <- (rbind(answers, x))
}
```

Ideally I'd like to do something like this:

```
answers <- c()
for(i in 1:10){
RF <- randomForest(training, training$data1, sampsize=c(100), do.trace=TRUE, importance=TRUE, ntree=50,,forest=TRUE)
answers <- (rbind(answers, RF))
}
```

This kind of works but here's the output for a single RF object:

```
> RF 

Call:
 randomForest(x = training, y = training$data1, ntree = 50, sampsize = c(100), importance = TRUE, do.trace = TRUE,      forest = TRUE) 
               Type of random forest: regression
                     Number of trees: 10
No. of variables tried at each split: 2

          Mean of squared residuals: 0.05343956
                    % Var explained: 14.32
```

While this is the out put for the 'answers' list:

```
> answers 
   call       type         predicted      mse        rsq        oob.times      importance importanceSD
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
RF Expression "regression" Numeric,150000 Numeric,10 Numeric,10 Integer,150000 Numeric,16 Numeric,8   
   localImportance proximity ntree mtry forest  coefs y              test inbag
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL 
RF NULL            NULL      10    2    List,11 NULL  Integer,150000 NULL NULL
```

Does anyone know how to store all the RF objects or call them so that the info stored is the same as a single RF object?  Thanks for suggestions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't grow vectors or lists one element at a time. Pre-allocate them and assign objects to specific parts:

```
answers <- vector("list",10)
for (i in 1:10){
    answers[[i]] <- randomForest(training, training$data1, sampsize=c(100), 
                                 do.trace=TRUE, importance=TRUE, ntree=50,
                                 forest=TRUE)
}
```

As a side note, `rbind`ing vectors doesn't create another vector or list; if you check your output in your first example you'll see that it is a matrix with one column. That explains the strange behavior you observe when trying to `rbind` randomForest objects together.

Comment: Why can't we grow them dynamically?  Is this a limitation of R?

Comment: It's generally seen as a bad idea to grow lists and arrays dynamically, because in most languages it's slower than just pre-allocating an empty array and assigning. That said, it's started to become a bit of a religious dogma to a fault. If you're writing code that's only going to be executed once and you're working with small arrays (like the OP, who only has 10 elements), it's such a tiny micro-optimization that you might not even notice the difference, and should instead just go with whatever is the most readable.

Answer (score 5):

Use `lapply`:

```
lapply(1:10,function(i) randomForest(<your parameters>))
```

You will get a list of random forest objects; you can then access i-th of them using `[[]]` operator.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize a list with:

```
mylist <- vector("list")  # technically all objects in R are vectors
```

Add to it with:

```
new_element <- 5
mylist <- c(mylist, new_element)
```

@joran's advice about pre-allocation is pertinent when the lists are large, but not entirely necessary when they are small. You could also have access the matrix you build in your original code. It looks a bit strange but the information is all in there. For example the first element of that matrix of lists could have been recovered with:

```
answers[1, ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers provide solutions to store random forest objects in a `list`, but they don't explain why they are working.

As @42- hints, this is not the pre-allocation step that solves the issue here.

The real problem is that a `randomForest` object is fundamentally a `list` (check `is.list(randomForest(...)`). When you write a statement such as:

```
list_of_rf = c()                                       # ... or list_of_rf = NULL
list_of_rf = rbind(list_of_rf, randomForest(...))      # ... or list_of_rf = c(list_of_rf, randomForest(...))
```

you are essentially asking to concatenate an empty object with a list. Instead of resulting in a list of length 1 (the random forest model), this statement results in a list containing all the random forest model components! You can verify this by typing in you R console:

> > length(list_of_rf)
>
> [1] 19

There are several ways to force R to perform the operation that you want:

1. explicit affectation in the list (cf @joran answer, although there is no need to pre-allocate):

   ```
   list_of_rf = NULL
   list_of_rf[[1]] = randomForest(...)
   ```
2. let `lapply` (or similar) build the list (cf @mbq answer):

   ```
   list_of_rf = lapply(..., function(i) randomForest(...))
   ```
3. encapsulate the random forest within a list, which will be simplified during the concatenation:

   ```
   list_of_rf = NULL
   list_of_rf = c(list_of_rf, list(randomForest(...)))
   ```

Finally, if you made a mistake and unlisted your randomForest model which took 10 hours to be computed, don't sweat, you can still restore it as follows:

```
list_of_rf = NULL
list_of_rf = c(list_of_rf, randomForest(...)) # oups, mistake
rf = as.vector(list_of_rf)[1:19]
class(rf) = 'randomForest'
```